# Passing System date to Sqoop

Tags: shell, sqoop

I have a hive table suppose student( id, name , date) and in mysql I have a table named student(id, name) , using sqoop I'm importing data incrementally and I want the system date to be added while I'm importing , how can I achieve that ?

Sqoop Query :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql:dbName --username userName --password pass --m mapperNo --query 'select id, name from syudent WHERE $CONDITIONS' --target-dir outputPath --append --check-column id --incremental append --last-value last_Value
```

and I'm writing this entire script inside a shell script and taking the current date using shell command and want to pass it inside the sqoop query so that while importing it addes the current date .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass thru variable,

eg:

```
cur_date=$(date +%d/%m/%y)

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql:dbName --username userName --password pass --m mapperNo --query "select id, name, '$cur_date' from syudent WHERE $CONDITIONS" --target-dir outputPath --append --check-column id --incremental append --last-value last_Value
```

let me know if this works.